# Sigma Algebra Notation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sigma algebra in $\Omega$ and let $A \subset \Omega$.   I was reading a paper and I came across $A \vee \mathcal{F}$.   What does this normally mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably shorthand notation for the smallest sigma-algebra containing both $A$ and $\mathcal{F}$, i.e.
$$
A\vee \mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\{A\}).
$$
If $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are sigma-algebras, then usually $\mathcal{F}\vee\mathcal{G}$ is shorthand for $\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{G})$.